# MS Access Macro to count records matching multiple criteria

Tags: ms-access, count, ms-access-2007, criteria

I have a table of Issues and Actions, in a one-to-many relationship.

I have a form OIssues, which allows the user to browse through each issue. It has an embedded subform which shows the actions associated with that issue, and there are command buttons which execute macros allowing the user to quickly add actions to the subform.

However I want to be able to prompt the user if they try to add an action which already exists for that issue.

Therefore I think I need to add VBA to the command button click which checks to see how many records exist for IssueID 1234 and are of the type "change request". If this is more than 1, prompt the user. However I can't find the correct command to do it!

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

VBA code behind the button.

```
Dim db as database
Dim rec as recordset

set db = currentDb
set rec = db.openrecordset("Select IssueID from YourTableName WHERE IssueID = " & Me.IssueID & " AND Type = '" & Me.Type & "'")

X = 0

rec.movefirst
If rec.eof = False then

rec.movelast
X = rec.recordcount
EndIf


If X > 1 then
  msgbox "This already exists"
EndIf
```

EDIT: I don't see specificly what your table layout is, so you MAY have to do some kind of join in the OpenRecordSet rather than just a straight "Select IssueID from YourTableName".

Comment: This seems good - I'm a bit confused as to where to put it. If I'm clicking the button to add the first action to the subform, then it errors as there are no actions to rec.movefirst rec.movelast. Can you please advise?

Comment: I updated the code, see if that helps.  Essentially, you have to check to see if rec has no records first, or you're going to get an error on the MoveLast statement.

Comment: It fails on the following line, saying "too few parameters - expected 1'."   set rec = db.openrecordset("Select IssueID from YourTableName WHERE IssueID = " & Me.IssueID & " AND Type = '" & Me.Type & "'") –

Comment: I was just ASSUMING those were the names of your controls (IssueID and Type). If not, change them to whatever your actual textbox names are. Also, YourTableName is YOURTABLENAME.  Change it accordingly.  And don't use the COUNT function, it's known to be inaccurate.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far Johnny. I actually did change the names of the controls, I just pasted the wrong code into the comments box. See below for actual code. Note I have replaced one of the controls with a simple text string, as this text string does not exist within my form.      Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("Select Arrangement from Actions WHERE Arrangement = " & Me.arrangement_id & " AND Category = 'Third Party'")

Answer (score -1):

```
A slightly better answer would be to use the COUNT function for example :-

Dim db as database
Dim rec as recordset
dim cnt as long

set db = currentDb
set rec = db.openrecordset("Select count(IssueID) from YourTableName WHERE IssueID = " & Me.IssueID & " AND Type = '" & Me.Type & "'")

cnt=0
if not rec.eof then cnt=rec.fields(0)

If cnt > 0 then msgbox "This already exists"
```

Comment: It fails on the following line, saying "too few parameters - expected 1'."    set rec = db.openrecordset("Select IssueID from YourTableName WHERE IssueID = " & Me.IssueID & " AND Type = '" & Me.Type & "'")